# Wii Broadway disassembly with libopcodes

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, powerpc, binutils, wii

I want to disassemble Wii game executable binaries in C, which use the broadway microprocessor and unfortunately the only disassembler I am aware that I can use is libopcodes.

Documentation about this library is scarce and I'm using this tutorial https://blog.yossarian.net/2019/05/18/Basic-disassembly-with-libopcodes to get a basic disassembler, from which (after reading) I copy pasted the last complete code snippet. I initially used the default binutils version of Ubuntu 20, which worked for the x86 architecture but immediately segfaulted with no output for my architecture of interest (bfd_arch_powerpc and bfd_mach_ppc_750). I now built from source the latest binutils version (2.39.50), which now demands an fprintf_styled argument (I provided a very simple one which vprintfs to stdout). Now I am getting an a floating point exception on buffer_read_memory (?) when disassembling the tutorial's architecture and a segfault when diassembling mine.

I am not familiar at all with libopcodes and am pretty much blindly following the only tutorial I could find for it on the internet. If anyone could help be up to create a basic powerpc disassembler with libopcodes that disassembles a void* buffer (or at least point me to any resource) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Didn't know that, I will consider cross-posting there

Answer (score 1):

A ppc example usage of libbfd can be seen in the `disasm()` function of [qtrace-tools/qtdis](https://github.com/antonblanchard/qtrace-tools/blob/3a83cc095de6fb6726c7c969ba8bbeaec75b62c9/qtdis/qtdis.c#L221). This is used to disassemble a buffer of powerpc64 instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It turns out that my call to `disassembler` was returning null. Following the readme I downloaded `binutils-multiarch-dev` but I still can't create a non-null function pointer with `disassembler`. Currently trying to figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I had to install `binutils-multiarch-dev` to support bfd_arch_powerpc and bfd_mach_ppc_750. In my case, I also had to remove my custom installation of binutils because the custom build with no flags apparently does not support PowerPC and `dis-asm.h` from `/usr/local/include` was taking priority over the one in `/usr/include`.